# Google+ .Net API - Getting Authenticated and retrieving profile

Tags: google-plus, google-api-client

I'm trying to get a users profile information for google+ via the .NET API but am having trouble.

1. Does anyone know if they have changed how the special ID "me" works?

In the documentation it says this can be used as a special ID to get the currently authenticated users information however this throws a 404 from both the API in my code and on Google's own test page https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get.  I was logged in when trying this.

1. Does anyone know how to get the user ID as I would happily use that instead of me but it isn't returned after the user authenticates as far as I can see (just an authcode)?

I also tried using user IDs returned when using the standard .net Oauth stuff but it isn't the correct ID, I assume it is for something else.

As for my method of getting to this stage, I first downloaded the example files here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted

They don't have a plus example so I took the Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2 example and swapped out tasks (which worked fine) for the plus equivalent.

I also tried rolling this into my own project.

Neither worked. I get the user forwarded to Google where they give me access fine and then when I return they are authenticated successfully as far as I can see, however when I call service.People.Get("me") it returns a 404.

If anyone could help with the above questions (using me, or gettign the user ID) I would appreciate it.

To the moderator who closed the initial version of this question, I have tried to make this as direct a question as possible so please don't close it.  This is a legitimate question I would really like help getting to he bottom of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now out of date given recent platform updates. Although the plus.me scope still exists and this code will work, you should be using the plus.login scope for retrieving profile data in C#. For a great way to get started with retrieving and rendering profile information, please start from the Google+ C# quick start available here:

- https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp

---

First off, the 'me' id still works and is unchanged. The way that it works is:

1. You authenticate the user using a standard OAUTH2 flow
2. You use the library to perform a People.get with the special value 'me'

The 404 error code is a little troubling, this means that the client isn't finding the endpoint. To debug this, you might want to use a packet sniffer like fiddler to see what the actual URL it's querying is.

Anyways, how about some C# code. The following example shows how to use the plus service to get the currently authenticated user (assuming you have authenticated someone). What's different from your snippet is that you need to form a get request for the API call, then run fetch on the get request. I've included the following example, for getting 'me', and the following code works:

```
var auth = CreateAuthenticator();
plusService = new PlusService(auth);
if (plusService != null)
{
  PeopleResource.GetRequest prgr = plusService.People.Get("me");
  Person me = prgr.Fetch();                                           
}
```

All of the configuration of the server and getting a client working is pretty hard and pasting all of the code here would be less helpful than just giving you a sample.

And so... I have written a sample application that demonstrates how to do this and also includes a wrapper that makes it easier to develop using the Google+ API in C#.  Grab it here:
[Google+ C# Server-Side demo and library](http://wheresgus.com/CS_SSFlow.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, to be honest the API is poorly documented and doesn't behave very consistantly, for example my problem turned out to be:

req = service.People.Get("me"); Person test = req.Fetch();

Which I was using Isn't the same as

Person test = service.People.Get("me").Fetch();

Which I'm now using and works.

Comment: Your post was on Jan 18, 2013 and that means you are using version 1.2.4722 or at least you "should" be using that. I was using that library since December of last year before I switched to the latest version. So using the older one (4722) and trying to: (1) get a `GetRequest`; (2) then do `ServiceRequest.Fetch` is working. That's exactly the same thing you are doing. But hey, there's no point of using an older version if there's a new one right (at least for the Google API)?

Comment: Thank you +von v. for notifying me, updated the post to reference updates.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to use:

Person test = service.People.Get("me").Fetch();

and not

req = service.People.Get("me");
Person test = req.Fetch();

Even though they seem to be identical the first works and the second doesn't.

Still not sure why google's own page doesn't work though.  Now to find out how to add things to the scope like birthday.